# lxc bandwidth control using tc

Tags: networking, bandwidth, bandwidth-control, tc, lxc

I am trying to restrict bandwidth inside my containers.
I have tried using the following commands , But I think it is not getting effective.

```
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/
echo 0x1001 > A/net_cls.classid   # 10:1
echo 0x1002 > B/net_cls.classid   # 10:2
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root \
           handle 10: htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 10: \
           classid 10:1 htb rate 40mbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 10: \
           classid 10:2 htb rate 30mbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 10: \
           protocol ip prio 10 \
           handle 1: cgroup
```

Here A and B are containers created with this command.

```
lxc-execute -n A -f configfile /bin/bash
lxc-execute -n B -f configfile /bin/bash
```

Whereas configfile contains only this entry:

```
lxc.utsname = test_lxc
```

AFter starting the container , I have started vsftpd inside container A and try to access the files using the ftp client from another machine.
Then I killed vsftpd in container A and started vsftpd in container B and try to access the files using ftp client from another machine.

I cannot observe any difference in performance, for that matter it is nowhere nearer to 40mbit/30mbit.

Please correct me whether anything wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is not well documented but I've experienced it before.
On 64 bit systems, the value you echo is *not* represented as a 16bit integer but a 32bit integer.

Try replacing:

```
echo 0x1001 > A/net_cls.classid   # 10:1
echo 0x1002 > B/net_cls.classid   # 10:2
```

With

```
echo 0x00100001 > A/net_cls.classid   # 10:1
echo 0x00100002 > B/net_cls.classid   # 10:2
```

This should fix your problem.

**Note:** Its not actually necessary to provide the leading zeroes at the start but for clarity I added them.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the non-hypervisor containers (lxc, jails) tend to have dodgy/incomplete metering (disk iops, net) that impacts other containers.  If limiting external transit is the main concern, stick a transparent firewall (i.e., ArmorLogic, Barracuda, etc.) in front of these first.

In any case, definitely load test to see if it makes a difference.

(ProTip: Heroku runs LXC.  `heroku run bash`)